# Python - If json element is "not valid", try the other one

Tags: python, json, if-statement

So I have been playing around with Json and Python and basically I have a Json file where sometimes some elements are not included and sometimes it is. Basically what I want to do is that check if the first element that contains "ImageUrl" is there and is valid then use that element, Else use the other imageURL

```
"threads": [{
    "id": "3a64a3b18894fb70c92b6382a1e8f735320c1cbb",
    "product": {
        "imageUrl": "https://hello.com/555088_401.JPG",
    },
    "imageUrl": "https://hello.com/images/555088_401.JPG",
}]
```

However it can happen that the first ImageURL can contain `999999_999` at the end and that is counted as invalid aswell.

What I have done so far is:

```
resp = s.get(url)
item = resp.json()['threads']    

itempic = item.get('imageUrl')  # Check if there is sell date
if itempic:
   image = str(item['imageUrl'])  # Image pic          
else:
   print('Picture not found')
```

which currently only take the second url imageUrl which is not what I want but it does work (also it check if the imageUrl contains anything aswell), The question is:

*How can I take the first imageUrl element and check if it is "valid" and does not contains `999999_999` at the end (If it is valid and correct then use it and print) else If it is not "valid" then use the second imageUrl*

Comment: What are you considering first and second? `threads:product:imageUrl` and `theads:imageUrl`?

Comment: @EastonBornemeier Correct! :) My excuse for not saying/meniton it.

Comment: The keys in a JSON object aren't ordered, so you can't really assume that `product` is "before" `imageURL` in each object.

Comment: @chepner Oh, The product is always before the `2nd ImageURL` - but does not always contain URL or 999-999 at the end.

Comment: Every product you've *seen* so far has the product first, but that simply isn't something you should assume when dealing with JSON. Object keys are, again, *unordered*.

Comment: @chepner Oh you are actually correct. That is indeed correct. I need to re-think in that case what I wanna do, do you might have any idea what I should think of now-ish :)?

Comment: Without knowing what the difference between `imageURL` and `product.imageURL` is, it's hard to say.

Comment: Alright! I will need to do some re-thinking, Appreciate it! I just saw you second answer, It is indeed a good start for me to go from! Appreciate it cheapner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check whatever value you get back for `999999_999`. It's simpler if you use the `get` method to "pretend" that a missing URL is a string that will match.

```
# This assumes that you want the top-level imageURL in preference to
# the product imageURL...
def get_url(d):
    for item in d['threads'], d['threads']['product']:
        url = item.get('imageUrl', '999999_999')
        if not re.match('999999_999', url):
            return url
```

As you can see, it's also simpler to just pretend that the second try could match `999999_999`, even if you know it won't.